# Incremental callouts

Tags: rest-api, integration

I have a rest webservice that returns a limited number of accounts for each call. How can I make incremental calls to receive all accounts and save them on Salesforce? For example at the first call I have to take the first 500, then the next 500 and so on?

Thanks

Comment: chained queueables

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents

First of all i think callout is a wrong choice here. If you are looking at bulk insert of records i would ask the external system to use bulk api to hit salesforce and insert records. At the least if they cannot use [bulk api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/walkthrough_upload_data.htm) they can use [rest api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart.htm) to hit salesforce

If you are still hung up on callout you will most likely hit other limits like heap size, time out based on the data transfer.If you still need to make callout and get data you can look at using batch class and get incremental data and update data into salesforce.

You will also hit uncommitted work pending error if you do a callout --> DML --> callout.
 you will most likely need to look at below options

1. Create a list of accounts,finish the callouts and insert everything at the end
2. Insert records through async ways like queueables or future invocations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The initial requirement is that it is only Salesforce that calls the external system to import all the data :( How would you recommend implementing a process that imports data from a rest service?

Comment: Whats the volume of data you are looking at?

Comment: I have no idea how much the database volume can be, this is because the rest service exposes data from instances of different clients (it is a cloud platform like to  zendesk). The rest service returns a maximum of 500 items per call with the possibility of defining an offset.

Comment: If the external system can give the data we could look at data  loading tools like informatica or data loader

Comment: Unfortunately, at the moment, only salesforce can call the platform and not vice versa. Some idea?

Comment: Batch class would work where you can call, get the data and insert into salesforce. you also need to look at apex transaction limits to ensure you dont hit limits in salesforce. Solution needs to be tested in sandbox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93347/discussion-between-reddevil-and-maidenfp).